# How to use 2 runners in the class

Tags: java, spring, parameters

I have a test class which uses @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) . Now I want to execute some test scenarios where I want my tests to be parameterized. Seems like I can't have 2 runners on the same class.

Is there any alternate way of doing the same?

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.blog.project13.pl/index.php/coding/1077/runwith-junit4-with-both-springjunit4classrunner-and-parameterized/) seems to describe how to do this. (*I think*. I can't really read it because of the dubious colour choice...)

Comment: Inherit + annotate child class with another runner.